# PHP 5 number_format() not returning exception message in local but it returns in production

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, php-5.3

I have this PHP snippet below in a PHP 5 legacy project environment(local and production):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

try {
    number_format("");
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
     throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
 }

?>
```

I know that this is a problem since `number_format` expects float or double. However it does not trigger the exception in localhost but it does in the production.

The actual message is `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /path-to-file.php`

I also tried changing `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` but it does not return the expected exception.

I also tried removing the `try/catch` and just use the `number_format` as is just so that exception error will popup the exception error did not display.

Also tried to add the `display_errors = on` in php.ini same result.

Comment: It throws an exception on PHP 8, not with previous versions.

Comment: @Olivier would be nice if https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php were to actually mention that anywhere. Did you figure that out by trial&error / testing, or from some changelog?